# Can't find my own app in ios wallet share pass list

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

I'm creating an application which allow user to share their passbook from iOS wallet to my app. It is working previously but my app missing from the iOS wallet share list after I change the cert and provisioning profile from enterprise to distribution. I have no idea what's goes wrong. Highly appreciate someone can guide me to the correct path.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution for this problem.
We just need to manually add in all the supported dataType in the NSExtensionActivationRule using 'SUBQUERY'.

For Example:

```
SUBQUERY (
                extensionItems,
                $extensionItem,
                SUBQUERY (
                $extensionItem.attachments,
                $attachment,
                (
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.adobe.pdf"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.png"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpg"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.jpeg-2000"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.vcard"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.apple.pkpass"
                || ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"

                )
                ).@count == 1
                ).@count == 1
            }
```

Comment: Where do you put that text above?